# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'thinc.backends.linalg' When importing Spacy

Tags: python

when I would like to import the spacy package for lemmatize, but I got the following error:

```
!python3 -m spacy download en

import spacy
```

Then python give me this error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'thinc.backends.linalg' .

Would be great if anyone can help me!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try uninstalling & Install again. Make sure that restart laptop/PC after re-installation of the `spacy` . Sometimes cache issue may cause some libraies fail to load.

Comment: Thanks, but How to uninstall `spacy`? Can I just use `! pip uninstall spacy`?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstall "pip install thinc"